# Propel ORM find by multiple conditions

Tags: php, mysql, database, orm, propel

I need to put multiple `where` conditions in my propel query. What is the best way to do it. For now I'm doing it like this:

```
 $employee = EmployeeQuery::create()
            ->where("password = '" . $password . "' AND username = '" . $username . "'")
            ->find();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `filterByXXX` functions:

```
$employee = EmployeeQuery::create()
           ->filterByUsername($username)
           ->filterByPassword($password)
           ->find();
```

Answer (score 3):

Use The filter methods based on the names of the columns in the schema

[The documentation](http://propelorm.org/documentation/reference/model-criteria.html) will help thoroughly understand it.

Schema:

```
<table name="users" phpName="User" >
   <column name="user_id" phpName="Id" />
   <column name="user_name" phpName="Name" />
   <column name="user_password" phpName="Password" />
   <column name="user_address_city" phpName="City" />
</table>
```

Query:

```
$User = UserQuery::create()
             ->filterByName($user['name'])
             ->filterByPassword($user['pass'])
             ->filterById($user['id'])
             ->find();
```

Keep in mind you can also use `->find()` similarly, but it's a terminator and will return and object collection

```
$User = UserQuery::create()->findByName($user['name']);
```

More useful for

```
$User = UserQuery::create()->findById(132); 
$User = UserQuery::create()->findPk(132);
```

FindOne() will also behave like this but will not return a collection, even if there are more than one results with the criteria.

```
$User = UserQuery::create()->findOneByName($user['name']);
```

Or a combination

```
$u = ClientQuery::create()
                ->filterByName('John')
                ->findByCity('Orlando');
```

As far as maintainable code goes, you should probably not use the last example. Use the first one. It will help with readability.

hope it helps!